# In MVVM, where are long-running business operations handled?

Tags: mvvm, architecture, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

In an MVVM LOB app, say I have a ViewModel that allows the user to launch a long-running business process, let's pretend it's the workflow of creating an order. 
When the `CreateOrder` command executes on the ViewModel, how does the `UnitOfWork` object (`DbContext` in EF) get created and managed throughout its lifetime? Is the ViewModel responsible for managing its lifetime, passing it off to some wizard dialog service, and eventually committing it to the database? Seems like a violation of SRP. But if the ViewModel doesn't manage this process, who/what does? Some kind of `OrderManagerService`?

Also, where does IoC/Dependency Injection fit into this picture? For unit testing obviously I don't want the ViewModel to instantiate a new `UnitOfWork` that's coupled to the database. But if this business process only launches if/when a user requests it, obviously a `UnitOfWork` can't be injected into the ViewModel upon app startup.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you nailed it with the OrderManager service.  You really don't want the accumulation of this change occurring in a view layer.  Create a PendingOrder object to accumulate your UnitOfWork pattern.  Put in in a memory-store, or an external data store (probably memory).

This keeps your view layer clean, and makes testing easier.

It kind of dissolves your IOC/testing issue.  Unit test your PendingOrder code independently of your UI.  Then you can mock/stub it for your UI testing.

Comment: Conceptually how do the OrderManager and PendingOrder classes relate to each other? Also, if I remove the creation of the UoW from my viewmodel, haven't I just shifted the problem of mocking the UoW away from my viewmodel and into another service? If that other service has to instantiate the UoW, how would I unit test that service?